# Autofac configuration validation

Tags: configuration, autofac

Does Autofac have an equivalent to StructureMap's *AssertConfigurationIsValid* method? Or does configuration validation occur when creating the container?

I believe the *AssertConfigurationIsValid* method checks that the container can create all the configured services. Obviously it can't pick up more subtle configuration mistakes - related to scope, for instance - but it would be nice to know that we are doing as much as we can to prevent issues that could crop up at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think Autofac have validation, and an exception is thrown at runtime if a service cannot be resolved. It would probably be useful but I always tend to write unit tests that validates that my container, or rather my [modules](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules), contain those services I expect it to have. Unit testing more than makes up for the lack of container validation.

These tests usually follow the pattern of

1. Create a container with the module under test
2. For each required service, test `container.IsRegistered`
3. Whenever possible, test `container.Resolve`

Comment: I easily implemented the unit tests you suggested, and now I don't feel too sore that Autofac doesn't have built-in validation. Thanks for your excellent answer.

Comment: How can I do this with services where I use factories to generate them? E.g. I have a service that depends on a few other services and a string. That string isn't registered in autofac and I usually use a factory with that string as a parameter to resolve the service. Currently my unit test ignores this factory and fails on the service because the required string is not registered.

Comment: @SamuelDebruyn in such cases, my test will resolve the factory in question, invoke it with some meaningful input, and validate the output. You could also have tests that validate that the factory fail in meaningful ways when given invalid input.